# Boot from USB - HP Bios Update with Ubuntu or?

Tags: boot, usb, hp, bios

I have an old (came with Vista) HP Pavilion Desktop model a6712f running ubuntu 18.04 (no windows) and plan to update to lubuntu 22.04.  A boot from USB option would be desirable but the bios does not offer that.  I see that some have been able to update bios with Ubuntu but I do not see an updated bios on the HP site for this old model.  Everything on the American Megatrends site is Windows based so I can't really tell if they have an update.  Are there any other options?  Is there maybe a way to force a USB boot from the terminal?

## dmidecode 3.1

Getting SMBIOS data from sysfs.
SMBIOS 2.5 present.

Handle 0x0000, DMI type 0, 24 bytes
BIOS Information
**Vendor: American Megatrends Inc.
Version: 5.39

Release Date: 05/06/2009**
Address: 0xF0000
Runtime Size: 64 kB
ROM Size: 1024 kB
Characteristics:
ISA is supported
PCI is supported
PNP is supported
APM is supported
**BIOS is upgradeable**
BIOS shadowing is allowed
ESCD support is available
**Boot from CD is supported**
Selectable boot is supported
BIOS ROM is socketed
EDD is supported
5.25"/1.2 MB floppy services are supported (int 13h)
3.5"/720 kB floppy services are supported (int 13h)
3.5"/2.88 MB floppy services are supported (int 13h)
Print screen service is supported (int 5h)
8042 keyboard services are supported (int 9h)
Serial services are supported (int 14h)
Printer services are supported (int 17h)
CGA/mono video services are supported (int 10h)
ACPI is supported
**USB legacy is supported**
LS-120 boot is supported
ATAPI Zip drive boot is supported
BIOS boot specification is supported
Targeted content distribution is supported
BIOS Revision: 8.14

Handle 0x0028, DMI type 13, 22 bytes
BIOS Language Information
Language Description Format: Abbreviated
Installable Languages: 1
en|US|iso8859-1
Currently Installed Language: en|US|iso8859-1

Comment: Does it have a DVD drive? Does the BIOS have a boot from BIOS option?

Comment: It has a DVD drive so I believe  "Boot from CD is supported" really means boot from DVD.  I don't know what a boot from bios is but don't see that option.  Listed drive options are the hard drive followed by the DVD.  I just added bios screen pictures to my original question.

Comment: I was able to boot and load from DVD.  However, it would be nice to have a boot from USB option.

Answer (score 1):

If you have an older computer or any computer that for any reason can not boot from USB. Check and see if you can boot from a DVD.

Make a live media DVD and set it to boot from that. Be aware an install of Ubuntu 22.04 from DVD will be very very slow.